# rewrite rule is not working in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

in my portal i call a pdf file, path looks like
     http://www.mysite.com/filespath/books/online_bliss_in_five_simple_steps_1339668056/live/online_dating_bliss_in_five_simple_steps_1339668056.php

for user acceptance i need to reduce this url. then i add a code in .htaccess file. after  adding this line only a white page is displaying when i call my portal
 the code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^book/([A-Za-z0-9-]+_.)/?$  /live/$1.php    [NC,L]
```

please help me

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want to do (URL before / URL after) ?

Comment: before i need domain name here -www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.askapache\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.askapache.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For more reference click [Here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the full path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /filespath/book/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+_.)/?$ $1/live/$1.php [NC,L]
```